# What is the relationship between prime ideals and their generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, finitely-generated

All rings are assumed to have unity: $1\in R$.

### In a ring $R$:

> **Definition:** An element is a **unit** if it is invertible (it has a 2 sided multiplicative inverse).

### In a commutative ring $R$:

> **Definition:** An ideal $P \ne R$ is a **prime ideal** if $ab \in P \implies a\in P \text{ or } b \in P$
>
> **Definition:** An element $p\in R$ is a **prime element** if $(p)$ is a prime ideal.

### In an integral domain $R$:

> **Definition:** For $a,b \in R$, we say $a$ is a **factor** or **divisor** of $b$ if $b\in (a)$.
>
> **Definition:** For $a,b \in R$, we say $a$ is a **proper factor** of $b$ if $b \in (a)$ and $a \notin (b)$.
>
> **Definition:** An element $a\in R$ is **irreducible** if it is not a unit and has no proper factors other than units.

### Known:

In an integral domain: 
$(p)$ is prime $\iff$ $p$ is prime $\implies$ $p$ is irreducible.

In a unique factorization domain: 
$(p)$ is prime $\iff$ $p$ is prime $\iff$ $p$ is irreducible.

### Question:

If I have a prime ideal, that is not principal (but finitely generated), say $(p,q)$, what can I conclude about $p$ and $q$? Can I say they are prime? In an integral domain, can I say they are irreducible? What additional criteria are needed to make these conclusions?

What about the other way, if $p$ and $q$ are prime, then can I conclude $(p,q)$ is a prime ideal? What additional criteria are needed?

I'm also interested in extending these ideas outside of domains and to noncommutative rings, but it's more important to understand them in an integral domain first.

Comment: In the first case, no, you can't say that $p.q$ are prime. First of all, there isn't one set of generators. If $p,q$ are generators, then so are $p+aq,q$ for any $a\in R$. If you were correct that $p,q$ must be prime, then you must have $p+aq$ must always be prime. When $a$ is a multiple of $p$, this means that $1+bq$ must always be a unit. Taking $R=\mathbb Z[x]$, $p=2+2x,q=x$ ,then $(p,q)=(2+2x,x)=(2,x)$ is prime, but $2+2x$ is not prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm skipping the questions about irreducibles. Too many questions here.

If you take the typical example: $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ where:

$$2\cdot 3 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})\tag{1}$$

Then the ideal, $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principle, and it is prime - it is easy to show that $R/I\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is a field, so $I$ is maximal, hence prime.

You also have that $2,3,1\pm \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible, but not prime.

It is also easy to show that **no** element of $I$ is prime, since you can show that $R/(p)$ is finite for any $p\in I$, and if $(p)$ is prime, $R/(p)$ is an integral domain, and a finite integral domain is a field. Thus $(p)$ is maximal. But $(p)\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$, so $(p)$ is not maximal.

So there are times where you can't find any prime element of a prime ideal.

In $\mathbb Z[x]$, $x^2+1$ and $5$ are prime, but $(x-2)(x+2)=(x^2+1)-5\in (5,x^2+1)$. So, no, if $p,q$ are prime, then it is not necessarily true that $(p,q)$ is prime.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Properties), in UFDs, every irreducible element is prime (which practically goes without saying,) but not visa-versa. The converse *is* true when the ring satisfies the "ascending chain condition for principle ideals."

Comment: Thanks, I've worked out everything except why $R/(p)$ must be finite for any $p \in I$.  Why is that?

Comment: Clearly my questions (about multiple generators) only apply outside a PID. I know that this example $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}]$ is an ID, but not a UFD. I'm now wondering if this relies on the multiple ways to factor ... if this still holds in a UFD where prime and irreducible coincide.

Comment: It's true for any $p\in R$, actually, and it is because every element $p\in R$ is a divisor of an integer $n$, and thus the set $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ with $0\leq a,b<n$ covers all elements of $R/(p)$. So there are at most $n^2$ elements of $R/(p)$.

Comment: Other than $\mathbb Z[x]$ and the like, I don't know many UFDs that aren't PIDs, but the key is that all of ours assumptions about what it means to be irreducible and prime for elements of a general ring/integral domain go out the window. It is worth knowing why the word "ideal" was chosen. Originally. they were called "ideal divisors." As in: Ideally, there should exist a GCD of $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$. Drats! Why isn't there one? Well, let's pretend there is one! We'll call it an "ideal divisor."It wasn't until later that the abstraction was formalized.

Comment: According to wikipedia, in UFDs, every irreducible element is prime, but not visa-versa. The converse *is* true when the ring satisfies the "ascending chain condition for principle ideals."

Comment: In my mind "$\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the like" can be very general. The way I understand things, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free ring on $\{0,1\}$ (and thus the smallest free ring with unity).  Then by adjoining indeterminates (but not necessarily allowing them to commute with existing elements) you can get any larger free ring, and then by imposing relations (by modding out ideals in that free ring), one can get any ring that exists.

Comment: Something's not right about the 'visa-versa' part, but between Wikipedia, you, and then me, I'm not sure where the miscommunication / misunderstanding lies. In IDs (where irreducible is defined), every prime is irreducible. In UFDs, every irreducible is prime so they are equivalent (since every UFD is an ID). I originally removed this from my 'Known' section, but I've added it back.

Comment: When writing my question, I edited for simplicity, and removed everything about UFDs, but then tried to imply my question included UFDs when I said "what additional criteria are needed". Thanks for helping me understand generators better.  I think over the weekend I'll type up a similar question just for UFDs and reference this one.